# SSRS Chart Horizontal Label Height Issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Created bar chart in SSRS in which horizontal axis labels are coming vertically, which i made them vertically by setting rotation 90 degree, but now problem is their height. how i will control the height of the labels.

[image]

Please any one know the property which will control the height tired to find but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you click in the Chart Area, there are properties for `CustomInnerPlotPosition`. Within these properties, set `Enabled` to true and try adjusting the `Height` to your needs. These properties control where the inner chart area should start and how much space it should take up, as percentages of the whole chart.

However, it seems that the label fitting does not take these properties into account. If your labels keep the same font size etc. you may find that part of them expand off the chart's edges. You may need to adjust some other settings too, or use shortened labels, but the `CustomInnerPlotPosition` properties should help get the result you want.

http://www.douglane.net/fit-chart-labels-in-ssrs/